# permission denied to access to database tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, tomcat7

I'm working on Eclipse with Tomcat6 and I use PostgreSQL as database.
I try to configure Tomcat6 on eclipse but it doesn't work. So I download a Tomca6 server. 
When I test my application I put my .war in the webapps directory on Tomcat6.
But when I try to create a user in my site I always get the following error :

> permission denied for the relation User.

It seems like I can't access my database from my application.

However the user name that I use to insert data  has all privileges on the database.I execute a `GRANT ALL privileges to user name` request when I created my database.

Why do I get this error?

Here is my exception message:

```
Mapped "{[/getProjection/showAll/{movieId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<com.cap.theater.common.beans.Projection> com.cap.theater.controllers.ProjectionController.showAllProjection(int,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 304 ms
An error occured while trying to list movies : ERROR: permission denied for relation movie
false
nouveaute query is : SELECT distinct movie_id FROM Projection WHERE (day > ? OR (day = ? AND "DATE" >= ?))
Listing all movies..
An error occured while trying to list movies : ERROR: permission denied for relation movie
false
nouveaute query is : SELECT distinct movie_id FROM Projection WHERE (day > ? OR (day = ? AND "DATE" >= ?))
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the user has permission by executing the same query using a sql client? I know ive tricked myself before with permissions thinking I had them setup correctly when I didnt. PS take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation

Comment: thank you for the link. It is because of the permission on tables.