# PostgreSQL 13 :: ERROR: permission denied for table 'mydb'

Tags: postgresql, psql, ddl

Below I'm creating database `mydb` and populating it. Notice that the last step I perform is setting the password for `postgres`. This is simply to avoid password prompts during previous steps.

I followed steps in other `StackOverflow` posts, namely issuing the `GRANT ALL`s on `TABLES`, `SEQUENCES` and `FUNCTIONS`, but am still facing the below issue.

**mydb.sh**:

```
su - postgres <<xEOFx
set +H

psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
psql -c "CREATE USER user01 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'SomePassword'"

psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA public to user01"
psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to user01"
psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to user01"

psql --dbname=mydb --username=postgres -f /tmp/mydb.sql
psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO user01"

psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'AnotherPassword'"
exit
xEOFx
```

The script does not fail, but I also cannot access the `mydb` as `user01`:

```
jdoe$ psql --username=user01 --dbname=mydb
Password for user user01: 
psql (13.2)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=> \c
You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "user01".
mydb=> \dt
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner   
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | some_table    | table | postgres
(1 rows)

mydb=> select * from some_table;
ERROR:  permission denied for table some_table
mydb=>
```

**SIDEBAR**: I do notice that the owner of `some_table` is `postgres`, and would prefer that it be `user01`. Perhaps this could be part of the issue.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Note that I tried running `psql --dbname=mydb --username=postgres -f /tmp/mydb.sql` before the `GRANT ALL` statements, too.

Comment: Here's also a great insight into least privilege setup in [psql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547993/1736679)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are granting privileges to tables, sequences, and functions in the public schema in the database postgres, not mydb.  By default, psql will connect to the database named the same as the current user, which is postgres in this case.  Make sure you run the commands in mydb by adding `-d mydb` to your psql commands.

Comment: I see. `UpVoted`. Let me rearrange things using your suggestion and retry. I'll select this as the answer if it works. Be back soon. `LoL`. Thank you.

Comment: It was a combination of what you indicated along with a `./pg_hba.conf` problem, but both were necessary. Thank you for the information.