# Django model error: ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation gallery_image

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I made a mistake and overwrote the Django server's settings file with the local version and I lost the database settings for postgresql I have setup a new user and when I tried to reload the site again I get an error from one of the models as `permission denied for relation gallery_image`

if I try this command from the shell

```
from gallery.models import Image
```

I get back

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation gallery_image
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions to the new user(In the postgre shell)
[This looks close enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation).

Comment: I've already tried postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE color_db to revamp;
GRANT

Comment: Take a look at the first answer in the link ive posted. you need to grant on specific tables - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE Image TO revamp;