# PostgreSQL database dump: makes it sense to grant all privileges on user backup?

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a database backup of a postgresql database. 
I did this on my existing database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql oder psql -U postgres
CREATE USER backup;                                                                          
ALTER USER backup WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE confluence TO backup; 
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE taiga TO backup;  
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO backup; 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
```

If I run `pg_dump -Fc confluence > dumpfile` I get

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation EVENTS
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public."EVENTS" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

In [Permission denied for relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation) I read that this would help:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE confluence TO backup;
```

I wonder if it is the rigth way to give all privileges to a backup user who shall not have the permissions to write the database. I want it to be a read only user. 
Is this a nonsense requirement?

What do you suggest me to do instead?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to grant CONNECT permission on the database and SELECT permission on all tables (in the public schema), you also need to grant **select** on **all sequences** (in the public schema):

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>
```

So to summarize:

```sql
--Create user
CREATE USER backup;                                                                          
ALTER USER backup WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';

--Grant read only privileges
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE <database> TO backup; 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;  -- new!

--Automatically grant read only privileges on new tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
```