# Permission denied querying a view in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, view, amazon-redshift

Why do I get permission denied when querying a view in AWS Redshift but not when running the query used to make the view?

When I try to run:

```
SELECT * FROM "dev"."public"."stg_kfdb_answers_flattened";
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation answers [ErrorId: 1-63c08c6b-616566234b35efdf64d5f06c]
```

But stg_kfdb_answers_flattened is a view, with the definition being:

```
CREATE
OR
REPLACE
  VIEW "public".stg_kfdb_answers_flattened AS
SELECT
  json_extract_path_text(answers.document ::text, '_id' ::text) AS id,
  <etc.>,
FROM
  <source_schema>.<source_table>;
```

When I run the query by itself, it works just fine. But when I create the view, as you see above, it gives me a permission denied error.

I have already tried giving myself permissions with statements like from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to jerry;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to jerry;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to jerry;
```

But none of these have seemed to help. What am I doing wrong?