# How to fix have SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation

Tags: amazon-redshift

I try to run query and got this error message

SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation name_field
db in redshift

here full details error

already try run this
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE name_field TO nameuser;
following this reference
[Permission denied for relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing the user you're using may be in a group that has an explicit REVOKE on it that is overriding the grant.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter user  <username>  with createdb;
```

should work.